# FireBreath Mac OS X Foundation

Tags: c++, macos, firebreath, browser-plugin

I am getting a link error on the Mac build of my FireBreath plugin looking like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IOIteratorNext", referenced from:
      MyFunction(...) in MyFile.o
```

**Please help me solve this link error.**

I have similar errors for `"_IOObjectRelease", "_IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty", "_IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry", "_IOServiceGetMatchingServices", "_IOServiceMatching", and "_kIOMasterPortDefault"`.
This leads me to believe that I need to include the Frameworks IOKIT and COREFOUNDATION.

I have concluded that these are the Frameworks that I need because I can temporarily get the build to succeed by adding them directly to Xcode like this:

1. In the project navigator select the project.
2. Select the target.
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab.
4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander (You may have to use
   'Add Build Phase').
5. Click the '+' button once to add each of the Frameworks.

After adding the Frameworks through Xcode, the build succeeds. However, once the prep script 'prepmac.sh' is run again, the Frameworks are lost and the build fails.

I have tried adding the Frameworks through FireBreath in several ways by editing PluginConfig.cmake and Mac/projectDef.cmake, and even considered modifying CMakeLists.txt, but this seems less promising.

I have tried the following statements in various combinations within the two `.cmake` files, but I am not confident about where to put them:

```
find_library(IOKIT_FRAMEWORK IOKit)
message("Finding library IOKit: ${IOKIT_FRAMEWORK}")

find_library(COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK CoreFoundation)
message("Finding library CoreFoundation: ${COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK}")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK}
    ${IOKIT_FRAMEWORK}
    ${PLUGIN_INTERNAL_DEPS}
)
```

None of the changes seem to change the build log.
Of course I am generating the project between changes with "prepmac.sh", in which the new 'message' statements report:

```
Finding library IOKit: /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework
Finding library CoreFoundation: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework
```

---

**Solution**:
Based on advice from taxilian the solution was both to correctly specify the correct Frameworks in Mac/projectDef.cmake and completely delete the build directory and remake it from scratch with the prepmac.sh script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply doing a find_library is not enough to make it link; you need to add it to a target_link_libraries call as well.  Also you should really make sure that your case matches the libraries themselves; I don't know if that matters or not on mac, but it's good practice in case it's a case sensitive filesystem (and yes that's possible to have on mac).

The correct case for the frameworks is "IOKit" and "CoreFoundation"

You can find more information on how to do this correctly on the [Using Libraries](http://npapi.com/x/WoAT) page on [firebreath.org](http://firebreath.org). Try something like this:

```
find_library(IOKIT_FRAMEWORK IOKit)
find_library(COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK CoreFoundation)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${COREFOUNDATION_FRAMEWORK} ${IOKIT_FRAMEWORK})
```

Note that this needs to be in your Mac/projectDef.cmake file somewhere *after* the "add_mac_plugin" call.

Comment: Dear taxilian, Thanks for your quick answer! Yes, I had already been adding the frameworks to "get_link_libraries", but my "find_library" commands were not before "add_mac_plugin" and the case of my foundation names did not match your suggestions. However, these changes did not help. Note that I guessed at the framework names, so they are unlikely to be exactly correct. Any further ideas?

Comment: add a line that looks like: message("Finding library IOKit: ${IOKIT_FRAMEWORK}") -- that will show you whether or not it found the library.  if it didn't, you've got to figure out why not

Comment: prepmac.sh appears to have found them both: Finding library IOKit: /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework
Finding library CoreFoundation: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework. I am not convinced that these are the foundations I need for my particular Link errors.

Comment: That's possible. Google is your friend =]

Comment: It turns out that CoreFoundation and IOKit are the Frameworks I need. I know this because if I add them directly to the XCode project the build succeeds. OTOH, when I add them to Mac/projectDef.cmake via 'find_library', 'target_link_libraries', and the 'message' command you suggested, and then re-prepare the environment, then the build once again fails. So, the question is: 'How to add IOKit and CoreFoundation Frameworks to the Firebreath build?'

Comment: Taxilian, I just noticed that the statement "find_library(IOKIT_FRAMEWORK IOKit)" is returning the path to "Cocoa.framework". I think it should return "IOKit.framework". This is apparent because of the "message" statement: "message("Finding library IOKit: ${IOKIT_FRAMEWORK}")" which prints: "Finding library IOKit: /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework" (see my edits to the original question above). Do you think it is possible there is a bug in the definition of "IOKIT_FRAMEWORK" in the FireBreath source code?

Comment: Try deleting your build directory and rerun the prep script.